# Shared Object Syntax

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, preferences, shared-objects

In AS3 I would like to set the key of a shared object with the contents of a string as opposed to specifically naming the key.

```
so.data.test = "andy"   // this is the basic working system
```

I do not want to write test I want something like this

```
// this is a non working and incorrect solution but shows what I am trying to do.
String myKey = "test"
so.data.{myKey} = "andy"
```

Is this an impossible ask?

Answer (score 4):

Untested, but you could try:

```
var myKey:String = "test";
so.data[myKey] = "andy";
```

Comment: +1 I deleted my answer because you slipped in yours before I had time to finish it, also you did `var myKey:String = "test";` which I left out.